# Counting backward from an integer using Python range built-in function, related to parse trees

Tags: python, function, parsing, range, built-in

**The list range(1,10,-1) Starting at 1, and ending at 10 won't count backwards because the start value-1 isn't greater than the stop value-10.  **

documentation

**range(start, stop[, step])**

This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0.  If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised).

```
for c in range(1,10,-1):
    c +=1
    print c
```

> >

**so this works instead**

```
for c in range(10,0,-1):
    c +=1
    print c
```

> 11
>
> 10
>
> 9
>
> 8
>
> 7
>
> 6
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 2

Comment: Why do you think that parse trees have anything to do with `range`?

Comment: Here's the definition of range object from the python source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Objects/rangeobject.c

Comment: Please read the help documents on "What can I ask here" and how to post a minimally verifiable, complete example.  Also, remember to do your own research before you post a question here: "what is a parse tree" is easy to find on your own.

Comment: Ty for python source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should do:

```
for c in range(10,-1,-1):
    print c
```

alternatively, you can do:

```
for c in reversed(range(10)):
    print c
```

or:

```
for c in sorted(range(10), reverse=True):
    print c
```

Comment: I've always liked the wrapping in `reversed` approach, since it avoids unnecessary copies (it iterates in reverse directly), and it's usually more "obvious" than trying to reverse the inclusive/exclusive rules for beginning/end of a `range` (for example, your first example differs from the other two by including `10`; the others go from `9` down to `0`). Of course, since this is Python 2, you could even use `xrange` to avoid realizing any lists in memory at all.